# Routing a site-to-site VPN through my regular VPN service

Tags: vpn, openvpn, iptables, routing, cisco

currently engaged in live competitive red vs blue team exercises in an enterprise style Windows AD environment. My device runs a modern Debian Linux OS.

**`cscotun0`**
We typically connect to the lab/domain directly via ethernet, however I've discovered I can also connect via Cisco AnyConnect VPN, which might prove useful. When connected to this VPN, I can perform most operations as if I'm connected directly to the LAN. This tunnel's network interface is designated `cscotun0`.

**`tun0`**
I already use a consumer class (subscription based) VPN service for everyday privacy. This service can also assign a new IP address and/or geolocation on demand, etc. amongst other desirable functionality. This VPN is OpenVPN based. This tunnel's network interface is designated `tun0`.

**The Problem**
The problem is (I think) I'd like to route the `cscotun0` traffic through my regular `tun0` tunnel. Effectively I want to obscure my actual IP & geolocation (and be able to change my apparent IP & geolocation on the fly), while keeping my web browsing and other unrelated web traffic out of band (through `tun0` but separate from `cscotun0`). Only traffic pertaining to the labs domain should go through the lab's VPN. Perhaps I can manage this with `iptables` or similar?

Like this:

[image]

---

**Troubleshooting Details**
The Cisco authentication appears to be performed over HTTP (succesfully) via `tun0`, but then `cscotun0` is established and it seems ALL my network traffic tries do go through the new tunnel (according to `tcpdump`), and get lost in limbo; my web browser stops working, limited lab connectivity, and so on. Everything works fine when I use just one or the other, but then I lose the desired additional functionality that the other provides.

Comment: if i read this right?you just want to double hop so to speak.From one vpn connect to another vpn and then to the internet?

Comment: @VipulNair no, does the diagram help?

Comment: ohh you want specific(lab) traffic to go through cstun0 and other normal traffic to go through tun0?

Comment: @VipulNair sure. if traffic is destined for the labs internal network, it must use the labs VPN. all other traffic has no business on the labs internal network.